# How to call Synchronus blocking method inside async method in Java?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm Using Project Reactor library. Here is my scenario.

I want to call the blocking service inside my non blocking method.

I have a three different services, I called those three services from my springboot application. Here is my sample code

```
public Mono<Example> getValuesFromDifferentServices() {

  Mono<Example1> mono1=service.getService1();
  Mono<Example2> mono2=service.getService2();

  mono1.zipwith(mono2)
     .map(value-> {
         // some logics then
         if(value.getT1().getStatus().equals(value.getT2().getStatus())) {
           Mono<Example3> mono3 = service.getService3(true);
           mono3.map(f-> {
              value.getT1().setSomething(f.getSomething);
              return f;
           }).subscribe();
         }
       return value.getT1();
     })
}
```

**Note:** Above example is not the actual logic. But the implementation is similar to that

Even I tried to `subscribe()` it, I couldn't get the 3rd service value all the time (uncertainty values). I cannot `block()` the 3rd service since it is not allowed. How to achieve this?

**Update:** 3rd Service input would be decided after If condition either it should be true or not `Mono<Example3> mono3 = service.getService3(true);`
We should call the 3rd service if only the condition matches, otherwise calling the 3rd service is not required and which is not advisable., If condition doesn't match, we should not invoke 3rd service.

Comment: The mono tag is not for Java.

Answer (score 0):

This example is a little wierd but as I understand, you want to call the first two services, each give you back a single value.
After that you want to call the third one if necessary and set a value from this into one of the first's field.

Anyway, there is a simple solution, but with more information maybe we can create nicer stream. This stream takes adventages of flatMap, which eagerly subscribes into the inner publisher.

[The example was written in Kotlin, it's very like Java. The only confusig thing here maybe the `it` variable, which is equals something like this: `map(it -> it.sg )`]

```
data class Example(
    val name: String,
    val status: String,
    var value: String? = null  
)

class ReactorTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val first = Mono.just(Example("first", "suspended"))
        val second = Mono.just(Example("second", "suspended"))
        val third = Mono.just(Example("third", "suspended", "thirdValue"))

        val stream = first.zipWith(second)
            .flatMap { tuple ->
                Mono.just(tuple.t1)
                    .filter { it.status == tuple.t2.status }
                    .zipWith(third)
                    .doOnNext {
                        it.t1.value = it.t2.value
                    }
                    .map { it.t1 }
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(tuple.t1))
            }

            StepVerifier.create(stream)
                .expectNext(Example("first", "suspended", "thirdValue"))
                .verifyComplete()
    }

    @Test
    fun test2() {
        val first = Mono.just(Example("first", "suspended"))
        val second = Mono.just(Example("second", "active"))
        val third = Mono.just(Example("third", "suspended", "thirdValue"))

        val stream = first.zipWith(second)
            .flatMap { tuple ->
                Mono.just(tuple.t1)
                    .filter { it.status == tuple.t2.status }
                    .zipWith(third)
                    .doOnNext {
                        it.t1.value = it.t2.value
                    }
                    .map { it.t1 }
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(tuple.t1))
            }

        StepVerifier.create(stream)
            .expectNext(Example("first", "suspended"))
            .verifyComplete()
    }
}
```

Side note: if you're using blocking services in your reactive streams, those should be separated into dedicated threadpools. Like:

```
fun blockingService(): Mono<String> {
    //real service use fromCallable
    return Mono.just("fromCallableOnServiceCall")
        //for real service it may use a dedicated pool
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())

}
```

Comment: I forgot to update that 3rd service input would be decided inside If condition. Updated the Question

Comment: the example above is still valid, you can usethe zipWith(third) part as zipWith(service.getService3(true))

Comment: Is that possible to send input value `true` value from the 1st/2nd service? instead of hardcoding like `service.getService3(true)`. Basically it would be `service.getService3(mono1's value))`

Comment: .zipWith(tuple.t1) / .zipWith(tuple.t2).